# How to visualize octomap from octomap_server with rgbdslam?

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, octovis, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on a question asked in this link http://answers.ros.org/question/127581/rgbdslam-and-octomap/,

Mr. Felix answered, "Have rgbdslam send out the clouds+tf transformations and let the octomap_server listen." which I already did as depicted in the rxgraph attached below.

http:// s7.postimg.org/xw5l3rph7/Screenshot_from_2014_04_05_18_02_14.png

Given I had already did this, how do you visualize the Octomap? I read that the visualization tool is Octovis which I already installed but how will you render the registered point clouds to the Octovis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149026/how-to-visualize-octomap-from-octomap_server-with-rgbdslam?/) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-05-28**:
I am running into the same issue for not being able to map rgbdslam to octomap with /tf issues. SInce you mentioned that Mr. Felix's suggestions were implemented in your solution " "Have rgbdslam send out the clouds+tf transformations and let the octomap_server listen.", would you be able to elaborate on how you did that ( as your rxgraph is a very tiny screen shot )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The octomap server should output a view topics which you can visualize in Rviz. See the `occupied_cells_vis_array` topic.

http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server?distro=hydro

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on 2014-04-05**:
So octomap can be visualized in Rviz. How about Octovis? Is not the Octovis the visualization tool of the Octomap?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-04-05**:
Octovis is a stand alone tool as far as I know. You have to save the OctoMap as a .bt or .ot file and load this in to Octovis.